# How to keep keyboard from pushing action bar off screen

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar, android-softkeyboard

In my android manifest I have the keyboard set to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`. As a result, when I click on an EditText, it causes the entire screen, including the ActionBar, to move up. But I want my ActionBar to stay put while everything else moves up. How do I do that? My layout is using a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView. Also I am using a custom ActionBar, as in

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `adjustPan` use `adjustResize`.